# One-to-one vs Many-to-many with duplicate entries

Tags: sql, database

Say I have this very simple table with duplicate entries. Is the relationship between the `A` and `B` columns *one-to-one* or *many-to-many*?

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | x |
| 1 | 2 | y |

Undoubtedly a simple question, but I can't find confirmation for this corner case... Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Changed the content of the table to avoid stick to the math definition.

Comment: one to many relation.

Comment: I don't understand why... isn't the state of the continent & country columns symmetric?

Comment: Note that some countries are in several continents, e.g. Turkey and Russia.

Comment: What if I Change the names of the columns to "A", "B" and "C" ?

Comment: I'd consider different tables, with foreign keys, instead.

Comment: And the Turkish city Istanbul has parts in both Europe and Asia.

Comment: if a, b, c is in 1 table then there is no relationship. relationships is between tables.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comment this is a *one-to-many* relation. for clarifying, let's take a look at this example(I normalized your table into these bellow tables):

Suppose You have a table entitled with `continent` like below:

```
id    title  
---|--------  
1  | Asia
2  | Europe
3  | America
```

Now we have another table with this name `country` like below:

```
id    title     continent_Id 
---|----------|--------------  
1  | Norway   |   2
2  | Germany  |   2
3  | Canada   |   3
4  | Japan    |   1
```

also, we have a state table with this structure:

```
id  stateTitle     country_Id 
---|----------|--------------  
1  | Munich   |   2
2  | Berlin   |   2
3  | Torento  |   3
4  | Tokio    |   4
5  | Osaka    |   4
```